# How to make pseudocode in IDA more human readable

Tags: ida

Some codes in IDA are not clear enough. Especially when they do reference after calculation

```
while ( dx33[rdi24] );
  if ( rax35 != &WPP_GLOBAL_Control && (*((_BYTE *)rax35 + 68) & 2) != 0 && *((_BYTE *)rax35 + 65) >= 4u )
  {
    WPP_SF_sd(
      (unsigned int)rax35[7],
      22,
      (unsigned int)&WPP_b7e02e4f98cc3b1bbc566e561d210229_Traceguids,
      (_DWORD)dx33,
      rdi24 - 1);
    dx33 = Str;
  }
  if ( (_DWORD)rdi24 != 1 && dx33[(int)rdi24 - 1] == 46 && dx33[(int)rdi24 - 2] == 46 )
  {
    dx33[(int)rdi24 - 1] = 0;
    dx33 = Str;
  }
```

For some parts like

> (*((_BYTE *)rax35 + 68) & 2)

Can I change it to a more human-readable form? I remember changing the function argument type like int a1 to JNIEnv* can make the pointer reference more readable because it recovers some JNI function names so that

> ...*(_DWORD*)(a1+312)(a1,v9)

will become something like

> ->func(a1,v9)

But I'm not sure how to do this for other types.

Comment: Quite frankly in this particular case you may want to look at [WPP Software Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/wpp-software-tracing) and ETW in general for the first `if` condition. I am almost certain that this is pretty much some idiomatic way of how the respective [WPP macros get expanded](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/wpp-preprocessor). The GUIDs will vary across different pieces of software (or even _within_ a single software). I.e. this would be a piece you don't want to reverse engineer normally. Is this KM or UM?

Comment: @0xC0000022L It's a piece of code in dns.exe. I think it's UM because when I used Windbg the function in dns.exe didn't appear in all the kernel files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the listing more human-readable, you just need to add structure definitions,
for example:
type of variable **rax35** - obviously not **unsigned int**

there should be a pointer to the structure you need to define.

---

The first thing you need is to find the `size` of this struct or class. To do this, you need to find its `constructor`.

- If the memory for this object is allocated using the operator `New`,
  you can determine the size.
- If memory is allocated on the `stack`, then heuristic methods must be
  used here. That is, you have to manually parse the `stack frame`.

After the size of the structure or class is found, it's time to add it to `Local Types` in `IDA Pro`.

To simplify `static analysis` as much as possible, you should:

- add, if any, `pdb`-file to the project.
- for each function declaration - restore `prototype`s

Comment: But how do I know which structure should I define

Answer (score 2):

There’s no single solution for every case but basically you need to use the decompiler’s interactive features:

- Renaming
- Retyping
- Commenting
- Navigation between different functions

Just looking at small parts of the function and renaming a few variables to some name which makes sense can go a long way. Start small and keep making changes until things start to make sense. Sometimes you may need yo visit multiple functions to see how a specific variable is used to figure out its type.